# How can i make some calculations with a short range inside one text log, with pandas maybe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I need to make some calculations inside one text log.
Like count the number of warnings it appears inside one block of log.
The log has some lines indicating the test has started and finished: like:

```
START_TEST

  session01
```

All the lines of log comes here:

```
7/22/19 16:09:45:968 EDT] 000001b5 SystemOut     O 22 Jul 2019 16:09:45:968 [INFO]
7/22/19 16:09:45:968 EDT] 000001b5 SystemOut     O 22 Jul 2019 16:09:45:968 [INFO]
```

and so on...
until the log reach:

```
END_TEST
  session01
```

Basicaly make some counts inside that part with python, I think i might need pandas to use.

Comment: you don't need pandas to do this. But count what, by the way?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please clearly mention about what is your input and what is the output you are expecting. Also please share the code block which you already have. It will help the members to help you easily.

Comment: Need to count like how many times the '''[INFO]'''appears inside the log. That part I could manage, maybe not by the best way, but it worked...The second part which is find a way to access only the small range inside the log is where I'm having trouble. I could find the number of the index for each line, so maybe writing a loop to iterate between the lines inside it.